# Scaling Cloud Launcher Apps On Google Cloud

Tags: scalability, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I created a MongoDB cluster using the [google cloud launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/mongodb).

Is there any way to add more nodes using the cloud launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, once you create the MongoDB cluster with the [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher) it is not possible to (re) scale the cluster using the launcher. You will have to manually adjust the cluster to scale it. The MongoDB docs are pretty helpful in this regard; for example, here's the doc on how to [scale a sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/add-shards-to-shard-cluster/).